# Params not passing to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to pass a client_id parameter from one of my views to a different models controller, but it seems like the param isn't being passed since I get the error "undefined method `client_id=' for nil:NilClass" in the set_client method. What am I doing wrong? ANy help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<%= link_to 'New assessment', new_assessment_path(:client_id => @client.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
```

This is my controller:

```
class AssessmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assessment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_client, only: [:new]

  def new
    @assessment = Assessment.new
  end



 def create
    @assessment = Assessment.new(assessment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @assessment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assessment, notice: 'Assessment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assessment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assessment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  def set_client
    @assessment.client_id = params[:client_id]
  end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :trainers
resources :clients
resources :assessments
root 'pages#home'
```

Comment: You're creating a request to `new_assessment_path ` is that the correct route for your set_client method?, can you add your routes?

Comment: Add the respective routes section and the generated link code.

Comment: @RT5754 check my solution.It no need to create assessment object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error reads:

> undefined method `client_id=' for nil:NilClass

That's coming from:

```
def set_client
  @assessment.client_id = params[:client_id]
end
```

Which is being called before your `new` action due to:

```
before_action :set_client, only: [:new]
```

At that point, `@assessment` is nil in `set_client` because you haven't yet assigned the variable. Thus the error.

It has nothing to do with params not passing.

My suggestion is, remove the `before_action` and change the `new` action to:

```
def new
  @assessment = Assessment.new(client_id: params[:client_id])
end
```

Comment: I tried this and it no longer gives me an error, but it saves the client_id as nil. So maybe the parameter isn't being passed?

Comment: You can check what is being passed to the server by looking at your local server logs.

Comment: ok so when the assessments#new view is loaded its there: Parameters: {"client_id"=>"5"}, but when I then click 'Create' the parameter dissapears and this is whats there: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "assessment"=>{"weight"=>"32", "heartrate"=>"6", "bodyfat"=>"6"}, "commit"=>"Create Assessment"}

Comment: Ok. That's a different problem. You should mark this one accepted and then post a new question. But, the short answer is that you're probably not including a hidden field in your new form. But, we would need to see new form to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Main Reason for the undefined error is You are passing client_id to new method but not to the create method.
And What i understood from ur question is You want add a assessment to a client.

If this is your goal follow these steps

1.create association in respective models.

add the following line in Client.rb

```
has_many: :assesments
```

and add in Assement.rb

```
belongs_to: Client
```

2.Now change ur routes.rb.

```
resources clients do
  resources assements do
  end
end
```

3.Now check ur routes by executing this  cmd **rake routes**
 now your routes should be like this

```
/clients/:client_id/assements/new(.:format)
```

4.Now you dont need to pass the client id param manually.

Hope this will help you in solving ur problem.

cmt here if any..

Comment: Hi, thanks - this looks like the right direction. I already had the associations in the Models but not in the routes.rb. The routes are now changed but I now get this error on the form: "undefined method `assessments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f24f18fcc90>:0x007f24f2518240>" with the higlighted line - <%= form_for(@assessment) do |f| %>

Comment: Dude , can u try it by changing 
form_for(@assessment) -->  form_for(@assessments)

Comment: its fixed now thanks. Didn't end up using your method, instead used a hidden field to pass the param. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ok.But passing params to new method and again sending it to create method to hidden field  is not the best way in rails.I hope u will make use of this thing in ur future work

Answer (score 1):

Do `Assessment.find_by(client_id: params[:client_id])` in your `set_client` method.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the client_id in `@assessment`, and that variable is not defined when you are trying to set it.

`before_action`'s callback is executed, as the name says, before the action (AKA method).

You should remove the `before_action` and add the setter within your new method

```
def new
  @assessment = Assessment.new
  @assessment.client_id = params[:client_id]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

- 1.Set client in before_action
- 2.no need to create @assesment in new method

Change as below

```
class AssessmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_assessment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_client, only: [:new]

  def new
  end



 def create
    @assessment = Assessment.new(assessment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @assessment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @assessment, notice: 'Assessment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @assessment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @assessment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



  def set_client
    @client_id = Client.find_by(params[:client_id])
  end
end
```